# CMake Error buildir" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake

I tried to run

```
cmake .
```

but encountered this error:

```
In-source builds not allowed.  Please make a new directory (called 
a build
directory) and run CMake from there.  You may need to remove
CMakeCache.txt.
```

I did as instructed but got an error stating that:

```
"buildir" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

Comment: You didn't show how "I did as instructed" but a correct way is to run from build directory `cmake <source-directory>`.

Comment: Yup so 
    `mkdir buildir` 
    `cd buildir`
    `cmake` .

Comment: You forgot to specify source directory in `cmake` call.

Comment: How do I specify that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `cmake` in the build directory **with an argument** of the source directory.

Example:

```
$ cd /path/to/example-0.0.1
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_FLAGS=VALUES # etc.
```